# Prove that A ∩ (B ∪ A) = A using a containment proof

Tags: elementary-set-theory

I am having a hard time trying to get my head around this question:

Prove that A ∩ (B ∪ A) = A using a containment proof

I am really unsure of where to start, help would be really appreciated

Comment: Please avoid no-clue questions. See [How to ask a good question](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9959/how-to-ask-a-good-question?r=SearchResults)

Answer (score 1):

$$x\in A \implies x\in B\cup A \land x\in A \implies x\in A \cap(B \cup A) \\ \therefore A\subset A\cap(B\cup A)$$

Further, $$x\in A\cap(B\cup A) \implies x\in A \land x\in B\cup A \implies x\in A \\ \therefore A\cap(B\cup A)\subset A$$

This concludes $A=A\cup(B\cap A)$.

Answer (score 0):

HINT

Show that $A\subset A\cap (B\cup A)$ and $A\cap (B\cup A) \subset A$

Answer (score 0):

**Hint**:

It's quite simple: if $X\subseteq Y$, then $X\cap Y=X$.

Comment: Can you give an explanation please, I am very new to this topic and don't understand it well at the moment.

Comment: What is not clear to you?

Comment: The symbols and what this is really saying

Comment: It simply says that if a set $X$ is contained (possibly equal) in a set $Y$, its intersection with $Y$ is itsel. Make a Venn diagram to make it obvious (of course, it nevertheless requires a formal proof).